# Time limit exceed C++

Tags: c++

The code is to find the longest palindromic substring in a string. It's judged time limit exceed by an online system. The system gives me a feedback of:

> **Last executed input:**
>
> "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"

But I test this input in my local and find it have no errors. What's wrong with my code?

```
bool isPalindromic(string s){
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
        if(s[i]!=s[s.size()-i-1]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
string longestPalindrome(string s) {
    string result;
    int maxi=0,l=0;
    int p;
    for(int p=0;p<s.size();p++){
        for(int i=p;i<s.size();i++){
            string current = s.substr(p,i-p+1);
            if(isPalindromic(current)){
                if(current.size()>maxi){
                    result=current;
                    maxi=current.size();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
int main(){
  string s="ccc";
  string a=longestPalindrome(s);
  cout<<a;
}
```

Comment: Please do not ask "What is wrong with my code", because this is offtopic. Also, the challenge on those systems is, that YOU will learn something new by thinking about it. When we say you the solution, it won't help you in the long term, so and try to solve it on your own ;)

Comment: It is not an error. It is a time limit for your algorithm. If the time limit exceeded it means that your algorithm is too slow (and it really is, it has `O(n*n)`) I assume this is a task from HackerRank or similar websites.

Comment: I think the problem is simply that your code isn't efficient enough. You are using *brute force*, that is you are trying every single possibility and picking the best. I think you need a smarter algorithm.

Comment: One simple (but small) improvement is that your `isPalindromic` function should only check the first half of the string. If the first half matches the second half, then there's no need to check the second half matches the first. But even with this improvement you are still using brute force.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which is less brutal. I'm sure it could be more efficient. It seeks to avoid redundancy by checking all longer strings before shorter ones.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
bool isPalindromic(T&& s){
    return std::equal(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::rbegin(s));
}

std::string longestPalindrome(std::string s) {
    auto max = s.length();
    auto sub = std::string();
    for(auto len = max ; len > 1 ; --len)
    {
        for(auto pos = 0 ; pos + len <= max ; ++pos)
        {
            auto sub = s.substr(pos, len);
            if (isPalindromic(sub))
                return sub;
        }
    }
    return s.substr(0, 1);
}

int main(){
    std::cout << longestPalindrome("ccccccccccccccccccccccc") << '\n';
    std::cout << longestPalindrome("4353543543543543543dfdfdfdsfdfdsfdsfdsrdvdffdfmonkeyyeknom738trfgsdcvsdjhcvskcjisfucjvsukcjmvesukcjvewckuyvskjvsjhc,es") << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This online system ( Project Euler, Hackerrank etc.) sets some time limin in which your code need to be able to finish the task. Your code is too slow. This typically mean you need to look for a faster (lower complexity algorithm).

In particular your code is quadratic complexity (in the number of isPalindromic() calls), looking at every possible sub string. There is a lot of redundancy - e.g. if substring starting at i and ending at j is not palindromic, then you don't need to check substring (i-1,j+1) at all, as it obviously also can not be palindromic.

You need to come up with a smarter algorithm.